# JSP, Simple JSON - Parsing each key in the dictionary

Tags: json, jsp, dictionary

I have a JSON dictionary as follows:

```
JSONObject jsonColMap = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}";
```

I want to loop this in JSP such that I can do a for each key in this dictionary, do something. I tried to do the following but I run into an error:

```
aWF = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(request.getParameter("data"));
Set<String> entries = jsonColMap.entrySet();
Iterator<String> iter = entries.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext())
{
   String key = iter.next().toString();
   if(aWF.containsKey(key))
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

But this throws an error

```
java.util.HashMap$EntrySet cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: It complains at the line where entries is created and assigned

Comment: That aWF came out of nowhere.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line above:

aWF = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(request.getParameter("data"));

It complaints at the line where I assign entries.